# EXCEL: How do I count these specific criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

Example row:

0,
1,
0,
300,
200,
0,
1,
500

From left to right, I want to count all integers starting from the first value that is greater than 1. In the example set, the count should be 5 (starting from 300 and ending at 500)

I could just delete the first 3 values, but unfortunately there are too many rows. Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNT(INDEX(theRange,0,MATCH(TRUE,theRange>1,0)):lastCellinRange)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdD06.png)

Use COUNTIF function

Comment: That's not what OP wants.